# Why does my rule have no effect on a VBO list of unpublished nodes but does work for published nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, views

I set up a rule that is supposed to delete some unpublished nodes. I created a view with [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) for the rule to work with. The rule is triggered by cron, leads a list of nodes provided by the view with VBO. The rule loops through the listed item and has delete content as action.

The problem is that the rule has no effect on unpublished nodes, even though I found out that the rule and view as they're set up can delete published nodes. Could someone give me a pointer here, why the rule works on published nodes but not unpublished nodes?

Comment: Any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Anything about [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) that uses the Rules Scheduler, runs for sure with "Anonymous" authorizations. There are cases (Rules Actions) for which that auth is insufficient of course.

So a possible explanation for the cause of your issue, is that your unpublished nodes are not included in your VBO views result. To verify if this is indeed the reason that causes your issue, just check the views results you get by looking at the Views results without being logged in (so as Anonymous user). If those unpublished nodes are included anyway, verify if Anonymous users are authorised to delete those nodes.